# How to update model field from another model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model, form-for

I have two models

```
    class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :dogs
    end
    
    class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :owner
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
      before_validation :set_name

      private
      def set_name
        self.name = owner.name
      end
    end
```

and after submitting a form (and therefore calling before_validation :set_name), I want to update the Dog name to be the Owner name.

**Moreover, My question is: what's the correct formatting of `self.name = owner.name`?**

My form looks like this:

```
    <h1>Create a new Dog:</h1>
    <%= form_for(@dog) do |f|%>
        
      <div>
        <%= f.label :breed%>
        <%= f.text_field :breed%>
      </div><br>
        
      <div>
        <%= f.label :age%>
        <%= f.text_field :age%>
      </div><br>
        
        <div>
        <h3>Create a new owner:</h3>
         <%= f.fields_for :owner, Owner.new do |owner_attributes|%>
          <%= owner_attributes.label :name, "Owner Name:" %>
          <%= owner_attributes.text_field :name %>
         <% end %>
        </div>
        
      <%= f.submit %>
        
    <% end %>
```

You can see that the Dog doesn't have a text_field for a name, and this is because I want the owner name to be the dog's name. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep things in sync, without needing to store the name of the owner on the dog object, I would suggest moving away from having an attribute on the dog class for the name, and instead use [ActiveSupport::Delegate](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/Module:delegate) functionality to delegate the name call on an instance of a `Dog` to the `Owner` it belongs to. This would look like:

```rb
class Dog
  belongs_to :owner
  delegates :name, to: :owner
end
```

The above code creates a thin `name` method on the `Dog` instance that simply calls `owner.name`. This way no matter what the owner changes the name to, the dogs name is always derived from the owner.

Comment: Thank you! Helped a bunch. I have another question on my page and was wondering if you can help out with that as well? If not, thanks a lot for your help anyways!

Comment: Definitely, just checked it out and went ahead with a response. Let me know if you have any questions about my answer in the comments, and I'll be happy to elaborate and adjust the answer for you :)